# Computing size of symmetric difference of two sorted arrays using SIMD AVX

Tags: c++, algorithm, sse, simd, avx

I am looking for a way to optimize an algorithm that I am working on. It's most repetitive and thus compute-intensive part is comparison of two sorted arrays of any size, containing unique unsigned integer (`uint32_t`) values in order to obtain the size of symmetric difference of them (number of elements that exist only in one of the vectors). The target machine on which the algorithm will be deployed uses Intel processors supporting AVX2, therefore I am looking for a way to perform it in-place using SIMD.

Is there a way to exploit the AVX2 instructions to obtain the size of symmetric difference of two sorted arrays of unsigned integers?

Comment: The reason that general questions are frowned on is that the answers are too vague to be useful: "Sure, there may be a way to use AVX to speed up such an operation, but it sounds challenging."  Without knowing the general size of the sets, and the data types (integer? float? strings?), the range of values, the data structure, etc. not much more can be said.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your comment. I edited the question, I hope it is more precise now.  The sets are basically arrays of unique unsigned integers with an arbitrary sizes.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks, it's `AVX2`, i'll edit the post.

Answer (score 3):

Since both arrays are sorted it should be fairly easy to implement this algorithm using SIMD (AVX2). You would just need to iterate through the two arrays concurrently, and then when you get a mismatch when comparing two vectors of 8 ints you would need to resolve the mismatch, i.e. count the differences, and get the two array indices back in phase, and continue until you get to the end of one of the arrays. Then just add the no of remaining elements in the other array, if any, to get the final count.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! That's the way my algorithm works right now - except it compares single scalars, not vectors. I guess using vectors to compare would be beneficial only when encountering matching vectors of 8 ints - which is not the most common situation. Therefore i am looking for some alternative .

Comment: Yes, I should have said that the efficiency of this is going to depend on how sparse the mismatches are - if they occur at such a high rate such that nearly every vector compare finds a mismatch then you're probably not going to get a win from SIMD. (For relatively sparse mismatches (most vectors matching) though it could be a big win.)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your arrays are tiny (like <=16 elements), you need to perform merge of the two sorted arrays with additional code for dumping non-equal elements.

If the size of symmetric difference is expected to be very small, then use the method described by PaulR.
If the size is expected to be high (like 10% of total number of elements), then you will have real trouble with vectorizing it. It is much easier to optimize scalar solution.

After writing several versions of code, the fastest one for me is:

```
int Merge3(const int *aArr, int aCnt, const int *bArr, int bCnt, int *dst) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < aCnt - 32 && j < bCnt - 32) {
        for (int t = 0; t < 32; t++) {
            int aX = aArr[i], bX = bArr[j];
            dst[k] = (aX < bX ? aX : bX);
            k += (aX != bX);
            i += (aX <= bX);
            j += (aX >= bX);
        }
    }
    while (i < aCnt && j < bCnt) {
       ... //use simple code to merge tails
```

The main optimizations here are:

1. Perform merging iterations in blocks (32 iterations per block). This allows to simplify stop criterion from `(i < aCnt && j < bCnt)` to `t < 32`. This can be done for most of the elements, and the tails can be processed with slow code.
2. Perform iterations in branchless fashion. Note that ternary operator is compiled into `cmov` instruction, and comparisons are compiled into `setXX` instructions, so there are no branches in the loop body. The output data is stored with the well-known trick: write all elements, but increase pointer only for the valid ones.

---

What else I have tried:

1. (no vectorization) perform (4 + 4) bitonic merge, check consecutive elements for duplicates, move pointers so that 4 min elements (in total) are skipped: 
   gets 4.95ns vs 4.65ns --- slightly worse.
2. (fully vectorized) compare 4 x 4 elements pairwise, extract comparison results into 16-bit mask, pass it through perfect hash function, use _mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32 with 128-entry LUT to get sorted 8 elements, check consecutive elements for duplicates, use _mm_movemask_ps + 16-entry LUT + _mm_shuffle_epi8 to store only unique elements among minimal 4 elements: gets 4.00ns vs 4.65ns --- slightly better.

Here is the [file with solutions](https://pastebin.com/zic9pLfa) and [file with perfect hash + LUT generator](https://pastebin.com/0swXvkgM).

P.S. Note that similar problem for intersection of sets is solved [here](https://github.com/lemire/SIMDCompressionAndIntersection/blob/master/src/intersection.cpp#L1196). The solution is somewhat similar to what I outlined as point 2 above.